# TCPDF JSON Annual Leave Scheduling

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF in PHP and want to print something like an Annual Leave Scheduling Planner.
(Table which has Name of the Employee and Events (Calender) in one row per user)

I am using this very basic TCPDF-PHP-File:

```
<?php
include('library/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF('P','mm','A4');

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->AddPage();

$html = "
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        ";

$file = file_get_contents('MOCK_DATA-100.json');
$data = json_decode($file);

foreach($data as $student){ 
    $html .= "
            <tr>
                <td>". $student->id ."</td>
            </tr>
            ";
}       

$html .= "
    </table>
";

$pdf->WriteHTMLCell(192,0,9,'',$html,0);    

$pdf->Output();
```

This is the JSON-File for the users:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Emerson, Adam"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Irwin, Cheryl"}]
```

And this is the JSON-File of the events (calendar):

```
[
  {"start":"2021-06-21T00:00:00","end":"2021-06-23T12:00:00","resource":"6","id":"32"},
  {"start":"2021-06-28T00:00:00","end":"2021-07-01T00:00:00","resource":"4","id":"34"}
]
```

**Resource is the ID of the User!**

The Table should create the dates per month.
I found this code and checked, if its working - it is!

```
$month = date('m');
$year  = date('Y');
$day   = date('d');


if (isset($_GET['month'])) {
    $month = $_GET['month'];
}

$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

$days = $days + 1;

for ($j = 0; $j < $days; $j++) {
    echo "<th>$j</th>";
}
```

So now I dont know how to create an PHP-Loop which assigns the event (json) to the user (json)
depending on the id. Important is, because it is an calendar, that each event appears in the row of the user and on the right date in the column. There could be a simple "X" or something like this.

Here is an image, if this is too much text:

[image]
I am very thankful if you can help me to solve this issue.
Best regards,
Fynn

Comment: One of the most important skills in programming is to Break The Problem Down. You know how to create a PDF - great, you can put that part aside! You know how to parse JSON - if not, a quick search will show you, it's easy; so leave that part aside as well. Take all that away, and you're left with two arrays of data, which you want to relate together. You could [edit] your question down to a fraction of its current size, and it would be much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run another loop to check calendar and populate dates for each student. Sample code below.

```
$month = date('m');
$year  = date('Y');
$day   = date('d');

if (isset($_GET['month'])) {
  $month = $_GET['month'];
}

$file = file_get_contents('MOCK_DATA-100.json');
$data = json_decode($file);

$file2 = file_get_contents('calendar.json');
$data2 = json_decode($file2);

$stuArr = [];

foreach($data as $student) { 
        $id = $student->id;

        foreach($data2 as $cal) {
            if($cal->resource == $id) {
                $start  = new DateTime(substr($cal->start, 0, 10));
                $end    = new DateTime(substr($cal->end, 0, 10));
                $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
                $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);                    

                $dd         = [];
                if($month == $start->format('n')) {
                    foreach ($period as $dt) {
                        if($month != $dt->format('n'))
                            break;
                        $dd[]   = $dt->format("j");
                    }
                    $stuArr[] = [$id, $dd];
                }
            }
        }

}

foreach($stuArr as $student) {
    $id     = $student[0];
    $dates  = $student[1];
    /* 
    The above $dates variable contains the dates. 
    You can use in_array() to check whether a particular day is there in the $dates or not.
    Rest you can code for printing properly
    */
}
```

Now after printing the header days, loop through the stuArr to print X

Comment: It is good to separate the data processing from the HTML output. Regrettably your code doesn't work. For instance, where is `$dd` defined? I can however see what you intend to do. Also note that just using the inner loop, without the outer loop, will be enough to fill the array, because the student id is present in the calendar data.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! If I run your sample code, the page is empty. Do I have to include some of my code again? Regards @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Can we solve my issue together :) @KIKOSoftware

Comment: @Fynn, please read the comment in the code, try to add your code to display student information, this is a sample code and will not generate anything, I just showed the way to get the data from the 2 json objects

Comment: @SubhashisPandey thanks! I understand your code, but I have one question: What does the $stuArr[] = [$id, $dd]; do and how to use it?

Comment: I will update my answer with a code that you can run, but will take some time, say after 2 hours

Comment: @SubhashisPandey Okay, this is very very helpful for understanding. See you later!!!

Comment: @SubhashisPandey Hey, can you guess how much time you need? No stress and thank you!

Comment: @Fynn check my answer now, leaving the printing section upto you

Comment: @SubhashisPandey Sorry Sir, i am too incompetent. I dont know how to do the printing part. I know the basics in <html> and <php> but i dont know how to deal with this situation. How let I the dates know in which column is should be. Can you please help me once again...

Comment: @SubhashisPandey can you do it or Not?

Comment: @Fynn. This is not a code writing service, you have to learn how to create code yourself. I see no reason why Subhashis Pandey should write this for you. As to what he already did for you: Very nice use of `DatePeriod()`, upvote from me! The outer `foreach ($data as $student)` is only needed when the student file contains less students than the calender file.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hello. Thanks for your answer. I am very thankful for the help from Subhashis Pandey. I think he knows that. I really want to learn but i dont know How to assign the Array data to the specific table column and row. Thats why i ask Again. I Want to ask you if you can please help me.

Comment: Because of Subhashis Pandey I know how to Deal With the json-foreach Part But dont Understand how To Print

Comment: I understand. What you could do, to get yourself going, is to ask a new question. Show the reader an useful part of the array, and how it needs to be displayed. You can dump the array with `var_export($stuArr);`. Also show what you have attempted, and why that doesn't work. I think Subhashis Pandey already has been quite helpful. He can, of course, still decide to help you, if he wants to.